# How to PutItem in dynamodb only if the item does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I've got a table in dynamodb that only has a partition key, and I want to put an item in the db only if there isn't another item with the same partition key in the db.

I've tried using ConditionExpression attribute_not_exists to no avail.

The issue is that a certain item may not already exist in the db, so attribute_not_exists fails with an
Invalid ConditionExpression: Operator or function requires a document path; operator or function: attribute_not_exists

Edit:
Can you please post the full condition expression you used + the name of the table's partition key? –

```
Key: {
  username: event.pathParameters.username
},
ExpressionAttributeValues: {
  ":username": event.pathParameters.username
},
Item: {
    userId: event.requestContext.identity.cognitoIdentityId
},
ConditionExpression: "attribute_not_exists(:username)"
```

Comment: what `ConditionExpression` did you try to use? Also, what was the outcome: an error? or was the item silently overwritten?

Comment: I used attributes_not_exists, and I got this error: Invalid ConditionExpression: Operator or function requires a document path; operator or function: attribute_not_exists

Comment: Can you please post the full condition expression you used + the name of the table's partition key?

Comment: ^ Added in edit ^

Comment: Please see my updated answer, @Darkstar

Answer (score 5):

I just tried it with an `attributes_not_exists` condition and it seems to work as expected:

```
$ aws create-table --table-name example1 \
  --attribute-definitions AttributeName=pk,AttributeType=S \
  --key-schema AttributeName=pk,KeyType=HASH  --billing-mode PAY_PER_REQUEST
...
$ aws dynamodb put-item --table-name example1 \
    --item '{"pk": {"S": "abc"}, "city": {"S": "NYC"}}'
$ aws scan --table-name example1
{
    "Items": [
        {
            "city": {
                "S": "NYC"
            },
            "pk": {
                "S": "abc"
            }
        }
    ],
    "Count": 1,
    "ScannedCount": 1,
    "ConsumedCapacity": null
}

$ aws dynamodb put-item --table-name example1 \
  --item '{"pk": {"S": "abc"}, "city": {"S": "SF"}}' \
  --condition-expression "attribute_not_exists(pk)"

An error occurred (ConditionalCheckFailedException) ... 

$
```

### Why did your request fail?

Based on the request you posted, I believe the culprit is your condition expression.

Instead of `"attribute_not_exists(:username)"` it should be `attribute_not_exists(username)`. the `:` prefix denotes a value place holder whereas the `attribute_not_exists` function does not need a value, it needs an attribute name. Once you make the change you will also need to remove the `ExpressionAttributeValues` field because the value placeholder it defines (namely: `:username`) is no longer used anywhere in the request.

So, to summarize, this request should work for you:

```
Key: {
  username: event.pathParameters.username
},
Item: {
  userId: event.requestContext.identity.cognitoIdentityId
},
ConditionExpression: "attribute_not_exists(username)"
```

One last (super minor) comment: the request you posted looks like an [update request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html). I believe that for your use case you can use [put](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html) which needs a somewhat simpler request. Specifically, in `put` you just specify the entire item, you do not need to specify the key separately from the other attributes. Note that just like `update`, `put` also supports a `ConditionExpression` which is the critical piece in the solution.

Comment: This only works if the item already exists in the db. I get an Invalid ConditionExpression: Operator or function requires a document path; operator or function: attribute_not_exists when I try doing this.

Comment: This also only works if the argument is not a reserved keyword.